# What is the velocity of a fluid particle at the center of a infinitely long counter-rotating vortex pair?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

Let's take circulation strength of each vortex τ and distance between them is r.
I feel the answer should be 2τ/πr but my friend is  arguing its τ/2πr.

So my thought process goes like, if you have a single filament of strength τ then integrating the biot savart law with distance at r/2 we get the velocity due to one vortex to be τ/πr. So as we have two vortices I added the two velocities as both of the vortices would push it the total velocity would be 2τ/πr

Comment: So how did you both derive your answers? Diagrams and analysis need to be shown.

Comment: So my way of thinking was that if you have a single filament of strength τ then integrating the biot savart law with distance at r/2 we get the velocity due to one vortex to be τ/πr. So as we have two vortices I added the two velocities as both of the vortices would push it the total velocity would be 2τ/πr

Comment: Inprove your questuon - don’t add detail in comments.

Comment: Cool thanks, Actually I'm new here so it'd take some time and help from people like you to adapt 

Comment: So, it may help you to avoid downvotes and close votes if you start here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: You can [edit] your question directly to add more information and detail.